# How to write an efficient normal distribution inside a class

Tags: c++, boost, random, normal-distribution

I'm running my project under same circumstances (i.e. except of course the random numbers). Some times the experiment is running smoothly and sometimes is not. I suspect the way random generator is implemented. This is my solution by using standard STL

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(){
      generator.seed(seeder);
    }

    double Normalized_Gaussain_Noise_Generator(){
       return distribution(generator);
    }

private:
    std::random_device seeder;
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::normal_distribution<double> distribution;
};

int main()
{
  Foo fo;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << fo.Normalized_Gaussain_Noise_Generator() << std::endl;
  }

}
```

I've tried boost as well, generally speaking the response is better than my method with STL and this is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <boost/random/normal_distribution.hpp>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() : generator(time(0)), var_nor(generator, boost::normal_distribution<double>() )
    {
    }


    double Normalized_Gaussain_Noise_Generator(){
        return var_nor();
    }

private:
    // Boost Case:
    boost::mt19937 generator;
    boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, boost::normal_distribution<double> > var_nor;
};

int main()
{
  Foo fo;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << fo.Normalized_Gaussain_Noise_Generator() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

My first question is is there any thing wrong with my approaches? If so, what is the most efficient way to implement normal distribution inside a class?

Comment: What does not running "smoothly" mean?

Comment: @Pradhan,  I'm not getting the expected results from a stochastic method that assumes the noise to be guassian.

Comment: Ok. Just to confirm, did you intend for the gaussian noise to be standard normal? Because that's what you get when you [default construct an `std::normal_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution/normal_distribution), as you are doing.

Comment: @Pradhan, Yes indeed.

Comment: Ok, in that case, I think the difference simply boils down to your `std` library's `default_random_engine` not being as good a PRNG as `boost::mt19337`. To do an apples to apples comparison, could you try using `std::mt19337` as the generator in your first example, in place of `std::default_random_engine`?

Comment: The commonly used method to efficiently sample from a normal distribution, given a uniform PRNG, is the [Box-Muller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform). This is exactly what the [`libstdc++` implementation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.6/a01001_source.html#l01649) is using as well. So if you are using `libstdc++`, handrolling the generator likely wouldn't improve speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Box-Muller (mentioned in the comments) is a common approach, but it's relatively slow compared to many of the alternatives because of its reliance on transcendental functions (log, sin, and cos).  It also has a [well-known interaction with linear congruential generators, if those are the underlying source of uniforms, that causes pairs of values to fall on a spiral](https://pantherfile.uwm.edu/hinow/www/workshop_97.pdf).

If speed is a major concern, the [Ziggurat algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat_algorithm) of Marsaglia and Tsang is one of the fastest and has excellent quality as judged by statistical tests.  Please see [this paper](http://appsrv.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~phwl/mt/public/archives/papers/grng_acmcs07.pdf) for a pretty good discussion of the major techniques used to generate normals, and head-to-head comparisons.

Comment: Nice answer! And indeed, OPs problem is because of what you pointed out above - Box-Muller doesn't behave well with linear congruential generators. Both gcc and llvm use `std::linear_congruential_engine<uint_fast32_t, 16807, 0, 2147483647>` as `std::default_random_engine`.